# speech recognition gets unknown issue in android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I m trying to make an app in which when a call comes to the phone by using android tts it will speech the contact name of calling person(do you want to attend?). according to the reply of user the call should attend or end. in which i always getting a problem with the speech recognition(showing unknown problem) here i m giving my code, can any one help me to solve the issue.i was struck on this since last few days,any help will be appreciable..

```
  public class myPhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    speechcontact clsspcntct = new speechcontact();
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
        {
            String phoneNumber =   incomingNumber;
            String ContactName = objUtility.getContactName2(context,phoneNumber);
                mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
                speakWords(ContactName);
        }

        if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE && ph_state==1)
        {
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
        }

    }
    @Override
public void onInit(int initStatus)
{
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
             if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
    else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Log.d("speech log", "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...");
    }   
}

   public void speakWords(String speech)
  {
      myTTS.speak("you have call from"+speech+"do you want to    attend",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);


    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();     
        }
    }, 5000);

}


  public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");

    try 
    {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        String spch = data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        if (spch.contains("Yes"))    
         {
            // do smthing
         }
         else if(spch.contains("No"))
         {
            // do smething
         }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: no i m testing this on my device

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to your intent which according to the documentations:

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.

and you are using it with `startActivityForResult` , removing

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

from your code fixes the issue.

Comment: after using this flag only this speech recognition activity came in front when ringing phone.. if i remove this tag the voice recognition activity works only after ringing gets completed.

Comment: you are not supposed to show anything while the phone is ringing , because the user would be busy handeling the call. and if you are trying to intercept an incoming call you can't do that on android, read here http://blog.wangling.me/2009/08/why-it-is-impossible-to-intercept-incoming-calls-on-android.html

Comment: here what i m trying to do is when call comes it should attend the call according to user command. for this purpose i have to show the voice recognition activity ryt??

Comment: that is called intercepting an incoming voice call

Comment: so how can i make it possible??

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that do what you want, it works fine on 2.3 to 4.0.
On jelly Bean does not work. Google made changes and looks like Jelly Bean stop
the voice recognition during the phone ringing.

So if you are testing on Jelly bean, try your code on another device.